# What is the difference between Sys.getenv('PATH') and shell("PATH") in R

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I was trying to install a package in R for two computers.

On my laptop A, it is successfully installed and for the other one B, I was not able to install it. Then I did hours search on google and realize that the problem may be lies in the system (or environment, I am not sure if these 2 words are equal) varibles.

I used `Sys.getenv('PATH')` and `shell("PATH")` on my laptop A, and it generates exactly the same results, except for under `Sys.getenv('PATH')`, the directories all have "\\" while under `shell("PATH")`, it is `\`. That is the only difference.

Then I try to see if on computer B, the one that I was not able to install an R package, `Sys.getenv('PATH')` and `shell("PATH")` will generate the same result. I found that `Sys.getenv("PATH")` gives a set of reasonable directories separated by ;, but `shell("PATH")` says

```
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin /c PATH' had status 127 
2: In shell("PATH") : 'PATH' execution failed with error code 127
```

What is the difference between Sys.getenv('PATH') and shell("PATH") in R? The computer A is on Windows7 and computer B is on Windows10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sys.getenv` will retrieve a system variable (you can see the variables at system properties -> Environment Variables or by simply searching environment variables on Windows local search). In your case `Sys.getenv('PATH')` will retrieve the PATH environment variable.

`shell('PATH')` will run `PATH` command on cmd. I have seen that it might not work correctly on all Windows distributions.

The results of the two functions either with `/` or `//` are identical. In one case the result in `print`ed and in the other case it is `cat`ed:

```
print('\\')
#[1] "\\"
cat('\\')
#\
```

In general for getting windows `PATH`, `Sys.getenv` should be more reliable, but the result is identical if both functions work.

Comment: Thanks! But why on another computer, the one with windows 10, I got different results for `Sys.getenv('PATH')` and `shell('PATH')`? especially, the `shell('PATH')` gets an error. And in the `warning message`, why the `shell('PATH')` tries to execute a strange command? any ideas about that?

Comment: rdocumentation.org says "This function exists only on Windows: "  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/shell